# SQL is seemgly removing spaces that have been inserted by RegEx

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I am working on a JavaScript app, in which I am preparing my data replacing tabs with spaces using RegEx in the frontend:

`str = str.replace(/\t+/g, " ");`

So
`'tabbed        title'`
becomes
`'tabbed title'` and so on and so forth

This is then passed to an express route which then sends the data to my MySQL database via a stored procedure, utilizing the `escape()` method from the Javascript MySQL sdk

The issue is, when passing a string where tab characters have been replaced with spaces after the RegEx, the title is being stored in the database as `'tabbedtitle'`

When entering `'tabbed title'` normally, with spaces entered via my keyboard, the space is preserved. After the RegEx transform, it is not. It seems like SQL is doing something under the hood, or the `" "` in my RegEx is not a traditional space character (even though in all my of my research it appears it is a regular space)

I've confirmed I am indeed passing `'tabbed title'` to the db from express, and there is nothing transforming the data inside my SP. I've even tried entering a utf-8 space `\u0020` rather than `" "` in my RegEx, but the problem perists

Comment: Can you share your javascript where you sanitize the string with `escape()` and possibly also your stored procedure that is perfoming the insert. Something is off in there.

Comment: Do `SELECT HEX(title)` so we can see if there is some "invisible" space involved.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of replacing tabs with a space maybe replace them with a hyphen or some other non-whitespace character? Might help narrow it down

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).